# return clob as out parameter of oracle stored procedure to delphi

Tags: oracle, delphi, stored-procedures, clob

i have an oracle package with a procedure that returns a large dynamically created text string. Due to the size of it it cannot be returned as a varchar2 so I am trying to use a clob.

The package works fine, but i am unable to find a way to access it in delphi using an ADO stored procedure component. I have tried most datatypes for the parameter including ftOraClob but the procedure always raises an exception on executing the procedure. I cant find any good examples of using a clob as an out param. Can anybody help?

currently I am trying this :

```
spGetRTF.Params.CreateParam(ftOraClob, 'outRTF', ptOutput);
spGetRTF.ExecProc;
```

but i get the following error:

2.5 Type          : EOleException
  2.6 Message       : Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.
  2.7 ID

Thanks

Paul